# Is there any way to specify Generic type based on Annotation type?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a use case where I will be adding different Functional Interfaces in a list. I want to use generics with this list such that I could add only the implementations for interfaces that are explicitly annotated as `FunctionInterface`. I tried something like below:-

```
class GenericsInJavaAnnotations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Function<Product, Info> function = (Product p) -> p.getInfo();
        Supplier<String> supplier = () -> "test";
        List<? super FunctionalInterface> functions = new ArrayList<>();
        functions.add(function);
        functions.add(supplier);
    }
}

class Product {
    private Info info = new Info();

    public Info getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
}

class Info {

}
```

Using  `List<? super FunctionalInterface>`  as well as  `List<? extends FunctionalInterface>`  gives error.

```
Error:(15, 18) java: no suitable method found for add(java.util.function.Function<java8.Product,java8.Info>)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<java8.Product,java8.Info> cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Function<java8.Product,java8.Info> cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface)
Error:(16, 18) java: no suitable method found for add(java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String>)
    method java.util.Collection.add(capture#2 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface)
    method java.util.List.add(capture#2 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to capture#2 of ? super java.lang.FunctionalInterface)
```

I know generics well and agree that super and extends have different meaning and none covers classes or interfaces marked by an annotation.

Do someone know any workaround or actual solution for it? Or it's a possible feature that we should expect in future versions of java?

Comment: There is no way of doing this, and it's not clear why you would want to.  What could you possibly _do_ with a list of objects of arbitrary interfaces?

Comment: The example of list I used might not be the best fit. So, think about I have a map that contains respective FunctionalInterfaces with different implementations and I pull out one based on key and perform the action on that.

Comment: There's no way to express a generic type that represents types that are annotated with an annotation.

Comment: That's still not especially useful, because "perform the action on that" isn't something you can generalize among functional interfaces.

Comment: `? super FunctionalInterface` first time i see this :| @SotiriosDelimanolis but why is the compiler letting you create one then?

Comment: Good point @Eugene. Compiler doesn't complain about it at all until I start adding elements to it.

Comment: @Eugene You can still get instances of the annotation. `Function.class.getAnnotation(FunctionalInterface.class)` and add that to the `List`. It's not particularly useful here since it's just intended to be a marker annotation. Is that what you mean?

Comment: when you declare a list like `List<? super FunctionalInterface> functions = new ArrayList<>();` compiler allows creating it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but the question still stands, is there a way to say I want a collection of something that are potentially annotated only with XXX? At compile time? I am pretty sure no( your first comment saying so); that would require traversing (or maintaining a Set of classes that are annotated) lots of possible classes...

Comment: @Eugene Right, no syntax supports that out of the box. There might be a way to define an annotation like `IFunc` with a `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` and define a `List<@IFunc Object>` and then implement an annotation processor that validates how it's used, ie. only with values of a type annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`. **Maybe**, I don't have much experience with annotation processors. And it still begs the question of whether this has any value, XY-problem and all.

Comment: Not sure why it has been down voted. Can somebody give me a good reason? Like question doesn't belong here or I am asking a question without research?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that would hit the subtle difference between types and classes. `@IFunc Object` is a type for which an annotation processor may assign a semantic, but if it is something like “must have `@FunctionalInterface` annotation”, Java classes do not follow that. Classes never have the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation, still, they might be assignable to an interface type that has it. These contradicting rules won’t work. As example of a type that could work, is `List<@NonNull Foo>` as there can’t be subclasses of `Foo` contradicting the type requirement of not being `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing types and objects (aka instances of classes). A `List` is capable of storing *objects* and your intention of “adding different Functional Interfaces in a list” doesn’t fit, as you are not adding *interfaces* to a list, but *objects*.

You can’t even say that you want to store instances of functional interfaces, as in Java, there are no instances of interfaces in general. There are only instances of *classes* implementing interfaces, but these classes do not have the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation, in fact, having this annotation would be invalid for classes.

In other words, when you write

```
Function<Product, Info> function = (Product p) -> p.getInfo();
Supplier<String> supplier = () -> "test";
```

you get objects of intentionally unspecified implementation classes not having the annotation and it’s not even possible to determine that at compile-time.
Well, in the specific case of `@FunctionalInterface` we know that they won’t have it, as it would violate the semantics of the annotation, but generally, when a class or interface has an annotation, there is no requirement that subclasses or implementation classes have that annotation too.

There is not even any useful semantic in the property “this class implements an interface having the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation”.

I can write

```
interface NotEvenRemotelyFunctional extends Supplier<String> {
    default String get() { return ""; }
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
static class SomeOrdinaryClass implements NotEvenRemotelyFunctional {
    public void foo() { System.exit(0); }
    public void bar() { System.out.println("hello"); }
}
```

```
Supplier<String> sup = () -> "test";
// your intention is that your list accepts the object referenced by sup
SomeOrdinaryClass obj = new SomeOrdinaryClass();
// but not that object referenced by obj... I supose
sup = obj;
// except when it is referenced by sup?
```

So what’s the desired outcome?

- Accepting only instances of types that have a¹ functional interface somewhere in their super type hierarchy?
  ¹ or at least one
- Or accepting instances only when they were assigned to a variable of a functional interface type first, before we add them to a list where all type information is lost?

Neither makes any sense.

Comment: OK I get it - no way to do it at compile time (let's forget about if it makes sense or not for a while), but is there a way even at runtime to check that a certain type that I put into a `List` *is* (no idea of a proper verb here) a functional interface or a method reference. I guess I could query for all interfaces that it implements and check if `@FunctionalInterface` is present, but even that is optional... I am strongly inclined to say no, just wondering

Comment: @Eugene “a functional interface or a method reference” reads like you are confusing functional interfaces and lambda expressions. An object’s type may implement a functional interface (or even more than one), but that doesn’t imply that it is a lambda expression. As shown by example in my answer, `SomeOrdinaryClass` implements a functional interface, but instances of that class have nothing to do with lambda expressions or method references. On the other hand, a lambda expression doesn’t need to implement an actual functional interface (though current compilers ignore this).

Comment: ah! stupid me, thank you, it makes a lot more sense right now

Comment: I have to accept it for the time being. But still It shouldn't be allowed and compile-time error should be thrown.